# get calling function with more hierarchical depth

Tags: scala-2.10, scala-macros

The following code gets the calling function (like C _ _ FUNC _ _):

```
def __func__(c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._
    c.enclosingMethod match {
        case DefDef(mods, name, tparams, vparamss, tpt, rhs) =>
            c.universe.reify(println(
                "\n  mods "+c.literal(mods.toString).splice
                +"\n  name "+c.literal(name.toString).splice
                +"\n  tparams "+c.literal(tparams.toString).splice
                +"\n  vparamss "+c.literal(vparamss.toString).splice
                +"\n  tpt "+c.literal(tpt.toString).splice
                +"\n  rhs "+c.literal(rhs.toString).splice
            ))
        case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "NoEnclosingMethod")
    }
}
```

But how to get more depth i.e. get the name of the function calling the function calling the macro?

Thanks in advance for yoiur help.

Answer (score 3):

You could try inspecting `c.enclosingUnit` or something simpler like `c.enclosingClass` or `c.enclosingMethod`. After getting the enclosure you could traverse it and try to detect the parents of your `c.macroApplication`.

However this approach would probably be not very robust, because the typechecker can significantly rehash the trees being typechecked, so you won't be able to find post-typer `c.macroApplication` in pre-typer enclosing trees. I remember someone having these problems, but I haven't tried this approach myself.